# Windows certificate verification with timestamping

Tags: certificates, windows, certificate-authority

I have been trying to replicate the behaviour of the **Digital Signatures** tab on windows file properties. I'm using **WinVerifyTrust** api and **X509Certificates** namespace to achieve my goal. I've managed to get the exact same response for the **Digital Signature Information** section in the tab. However, I'm unable to get the exact same response for the certificate chain, and certificate statuses.

Case in point;

I have 2 pe files on my computer for testing. When i check the **Digital Signatures** tab;

- **File1** has a status of **This digital signature is not valid**
- **File1**'s signing certificate is expired, and it marked as **expired** in the tab. (Valid until **10.01.2013**)
- **File1**'s signing time is **13.04.2012**
- **File1** has a timestamping certificate, which is also expired and marked as **expired** in the tab. (Valid until **25.10.2012**)

It seems to me the timestamping logic is not performed on **File1**. Even though the signing date is before the expiration date of both certificates, certificate status is shown as **expired**. Lets have a look at **File2**.

- **File2** has a status of **This digital signature is not valid**
- **File2**'s signing certificate is expired, but it is marked as **CERT OK** in the tab. (Valid until **18.12.2012**)
- **File2**'s signing time is **04.04.2011**
- **File2** has a timestamping certificate, which is also expired and marked as **CERT OK** in the tab. (Valid until **15.06.2012**)

Now, what i understand from this scenario is that **File2**' certificates are not marked as **expired**, because the timestamping logic is performed on these certificates, and I think this is the correct result. However, even though the same conditions apply to the **File1**, the timestamping logic seems to be ignored on this file, and certificates are shown as **expired**.

What is the difference between these files? Am i missing something?

I also did check the **szOID_KP_LIFETIME_SIGNING 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.10.3.13** flag in the certificates, but i did not encounter it. Maybe i'm looking the wrong place for this flag?  Where exactly is this flag lives?

I did follow some instructions from this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329396/what-happens-when-a-code-signing-certificate-expires

Here is a screenshot from the digital signatures tab of **File1**:
[image]

Here is a screenshot from the digital signatures tab of **File2**:
[image]

Comment: Could you upload those two files to VirusTotal.com and share the links?

Comment: File 1 : https://www.virustotal.com/tr/file/7b0ac067ab81067e7150291db88ccaf810bd7f521d091b5656328aeb81c36e17/analysis/ 
File 2 :https://www.virustotal.com/tr/file/1cb0e365c87e8ec1e5997b945d62f158e146edbcfa824da3d0c78dd40934d603/analysis/